# django build_absolute_uri without query params

Tags: django

`request.build_absolute_uri()` returns me `url/path/?q1=v1&q2=v2...` BUT, I need the same **absolute uri** without query params `q1=v1&q2=v2`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`build_absolute_uri`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) method has an optional `location`. If no `location` is provided, it uses `get_full_path()` which includes the querystring. You can pass `request.path` (which doesn't include the querystring) as the location.

```
request.build_absolute_uri(request.path)
```

Comment: what if it is in template? Like {{ request.build_absolute_uri }}

Comment: @jobima doing `{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}` in the template is equivalent to `request.build_absolute_uri()` in the view. It isn’t possible to pass a location in the template because the Django template language does not support it. If you need to do this, you could write a custom template filter or tag.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding, if you want to do it from within a template, this is how to do it via writing a simple tag:

1. In your `settings.py`, add the following to `TEMPLATE['OPTIONS']`:

```
'libraries': {
  'common_extras': 'your_project.templatetags.common_extras',
},
```

2. Then, create `your_project/templatetags/common_extras.py` and add the following:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def clean_url(context):
    request = context['request']
    return request.build_absolute_uri(request.path)
```

3. Finally, in your template, you just do:

```
{% load common_extras %}
...
<meta property="og:url" content="{% clean_url %}">
...
<meta property="twitter:url" content="{% clean_url %}">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the entire absolute url but without your params there are other properties on the request object you can use and combine them (scheme, get_host and path). It can be used in a template as such:

```
{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{{ request.path }}
```